# How can I prevent angular from doing math when i insert an attribute as a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-directives

I am trying to pass an attribute in angular to my directive as a string something like

```
<custom-directive an-attribute="10/10/10"></custom-directive>
```

however when i try to access an-attribute it does the math operation and outputs 0.01. How can I prevent the attribute from doing the math operation?

Comment: Did you try escaping it? .. `an-attribute="10\/10\/10"` or wrap in single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an `@` or an `=` binding?

If using an `@` binding, `an-attribute="10/10/10"` should work as is. This may be what you want.

If using an `=` binding, `an-attribute="'10/10/10'"` should do the trick.

Comment: Am a bit dumfounded. Have had issues in the past using `=` and strings by accident